# How to change write permissions (os.makedirs) for conda?

Tags: python, permissions, conda

I am using a virtual machine on Azure for GPU compute. In a conda environment, I am trying to replicate a paper and train the model, but one of the preprocessing files (all files are in python) uses this code:

```
mkdir(name, mode)
```

Which give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ryuparish/multidoc2dial/scripts/model_converter.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ryuparish/multidoc2dial/scripts/model_converter.py", line 39, in main
    model.save_pretrained(args.out_path)
  File "/anaconda/envs/multidoc2dial/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 1029, in save_pretrained
    os.makedirs(save_directory, exist_ok=True)
  File "/anaconda/envs/multidoc2dial/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/rag-dpr-studentaid-structure'
```

I assumed this was because conda does not have permissions to make that directory. I then tried using sudo `sudo (same command)` but this will not recognize any of my packages in my conda environment.

How do I allow conda to create directories?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create a directory immediately under the root (`/`). Consider trying a location more respectful of [Linux directory structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) (e.g., under `~/`).

Comment: Thanks @merv! This was the issue, I will make an answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with an undefined bash environment variable which was supposed to be appended to the front of the directory to be made. Since the variable was completely blank (undefined), the root directory became the target directory, and that is where the permission errors arose.

I just set the environment variable, sourced .bashrc, and everything worked afterwards.